# What government agencies are officially designated as terrorist by another country's government?

Tags: terrorism

[In 2007, according to CNN:](http://edition.cnn.com/2007/WORLD/meast/09/29/iran.parliament/)

> The Iranian parliament on Saturday voted to designate the United States' Central Intelligence Agency and the U.S. Army as terrorist organizations, IRNA, the country's state-run news agency, reported.

QUESTION: What other government agencies (or countries themselves) are currently designated as terrorist by a law/decree of another country's government?

- I guess there should be few enough that they can all be listed here.
- I am talking about **official designation**, not just some state leader angrily calling another country as terrorist during a speech.
- Due to the semantic satiation of the word 'terrorist', I narrow the question down to official designations that include concrete penalties and actions due to said designation - otherwise an "official designation" is simply a more emphatic speech. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_designated_terrorist_organizations#Process_of_designation) for concrete examples of official designation processes (many countries have such an official process).

Comment: Nice idea but I think it simply highlights the semantic satiation of the word 'terrorist'. You'll need to narrow the question down to official designations that include concrete penalties and actions due to said designation - otherwise an "official designation" is simply a more empathic speech.

Comment: Oop. I meant emphatic. An empathic speech about terrorists would be highly unusual considering the subject matter.

Answer (score 7):

Sudan, Iran, and Syria, listed [here](http://www.state.gov/j/ct/list/c14151.htm).
UPD: Cuba was on this list [until May 2015](http://www.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2015/05/242986.htm).

As to historical examples, the Palestine Liberation Organization was considered by both the United States and Israel to be a terrorist organization until 1991.
The African National Congress, South Africa's now-governing political party, was considered terrorist by the United States until 2008.

Comment: I think @nic was asking about countries other than the United States; and probably countries other than the USA's common allies. On a side note, the lingering 21st century bans were/are against specific ANC members; and the US' reasons for adding or removing people from their T.E.L. is opaque and deeply political, so we can't easily extrapolate to entire post-apartheid political parties.

Comment: +1 The US' list is exactly the kind of lists I was looking for, thanks! Was PLO a government agency when it was designated? I don't think the ANC has ever been a government agency, right?

Comment: Ah in that case, I rescind my assumption. +1 ish.

Comment: @LateralFractal Thanks for your note. I agree about the ANC, my thinking was too broad. AFAIK, the US is the only country keeping a list of "terrorist states." Other countries prefer listing specific organizations and people, i.e. there is the [EU's list](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServLexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2013:201:0057:0059:EN:PDF) and then each EU member state may amend it. Besides, the UN keeps [country reports](http://www.un.org/en/sc/ctc/resources/1624.html) on compliance with Security Council [resolutions](http://www.un.org/en/terrorism/instruments.shtml)

Comment: @nic Glad you've found what you wanted. The PLO was more than a government agency, it _was_ Palestine. Since 1974, the PLO was called (by the UN among others) "the sole legitimate representative of the Palestinian people." And in 1988, after declaration of independence, Arafat assumed the title of "President of Palestine" _as_ Chairman of the PLO. The ANC is not an agency, you're right. (I was thinking more of "governing" than of "legal status" here).

Comment: Are you sure about the date (2008) for the ANC? They are running the country since 1994, it looks a bit strange that they would have considered themselves terrorists for 14 years.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I didn't say they _considered themselves_ terrorist. I said that the US considered them to be terrorist - until President Bush Jr. has signed a bill removing Nelson Mandela and others from the terrorist watch list [**in 2008**](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/news/washington/2008-07-01-bush-mandela_N.htm). It's [still not revealed](http://loweringthebar.net/2008/07/nelson-mandela.html) though whether all members of the ANC were cleared.

Comment: You wrote "was considered terrorist by both the **Republic of South Africa** and the United States **until 2008**". I guess the first one needs a different end year.

Comment: How embarrassing... Partially because you are the first one who noticed. Honestly, I've no idea what I was thinking at the time of writing. Possibly, just mixed together two things: both South Africa (old regime) and the US labeled ANC terrorist at the time, and then the US removed Mandela & ANC in 2008. Thanks a lot for bringing my attention to this.